Problem from the book "Mechanics" by Landau and Lifshitz (§7, Page 16)
In L&L book "Mechanics" $3rd$ edition Volume $1$, there is this one problem on page $16$ at the end of the "conservation laws" chapter stating the following:
A particle of mass $\mathbf{m}$ moving with velocity $\vec{\mathbf{v_1}}$ leaves a half-space in which its potential energy is a constant $\mathbf{U_1}$ and enters another in which its potential energy is a different constant $\mathbf{U_2}$. Determine the change in the direction of motion of the particle.
Landau also provides this solution:
The potential energy is independent of the coordinates whose axes are parallel to the plane separating the half-spaces. The component of momentum in that plane is therefore conserved. Denoting by $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ the angles between the normal to the plane and the velocities $\vec{\mathbf{v_1}}$ and $\vec{\mathbf{v_2}}$ of the particle before and after passing the plane, we have $v_1 \sin(\theta_1) = v_2 \sin(\theta_2)$ The relation between $v_1$ and $v_2$ is given by the law of conservation of energy, and the result is
$$
\frac{\sin(\theta_1)}{\sin(\theta_2)} = \sqrt{1 + \frac{2(U_1 - U_2)}{m v_1^2}} 
$$
From this answer provided by the book, I assumed that the problem was taking place in $2$-dimensional space since there was an angle $\theta$ measured from just one axis. I evaluated the solution in the following manner:
$\hskip2in$$U_1$ to $U_1$" />
From conservation of the energy we have:
$${1\over 2}mv_1^2 + U_1 = {1\over 2}mv_2^2 + U_2$$
Now from conservation of momentum next is true:
$$mv_1\sin(\theta_1)=mv_2\sin(\theta_2)$$
And finally we substitute and get the answer
$$
\frac{\sin(\theta_1)}{\sin(\theta_2)} = \sqrt{1 + \frac{2(U_1 - U_2)}{m v_1^2}} 
$$
$\mathbf{Now\ here\ is\ what\ I\ don't\ get\ and\ need\ some\ help\ with\ understanding\ it: \ }$
Why are we staying on $2$-dimensional space? I thought half-space was $3$-dimensional region satisfying $\ x>0$, $\ -\infty<y<\infty$, $\ -\infty<z<\infty \ $ and in this case wouldn't we needed some second angle measured from third axis to radius vector to describe particle motion completely? In a nutshell - why are we solving this problem on a plane while problem states $\ \mathbf{half}$$\mathbf{-}$$\mathbf{space}\ $ and not half-plane? $\mathbf{Beside\ this\ question\ there\ is\ one\ more\ }$   - why does $\frac{\sin(\theta_1)}{\sin(\theta_2)}$ determine the change in the direction of motion of the particle?

The plane is the boundary between the two half spaces.

You can always orient your axes in such a way so as to work on the plane spanned by the two velocities.

Thank you so much, but it's still not clear for me why are we solving problem on that boundary plane and not in the whole (both) half-spaces?

@DamianSowinski But as plane is rotating by velocity vector, the equations of motion doesn't change relative to 3-D space (or half-space)?

Note that $\theta_i$ is the angle between the normal vector and $\vec{v}_i$. This generally defines a cone, when you think about all the possible vectors that can have this angle to the normal vector. That's the extra freedom that will always be unconstrained in this problem

@QuantumMechanic Ohhh... I thought $\theta_i$ was angle between, in this case, y axis and velocity vector before particle left boundary plane. Thank you

That's what I thought you thought :)

Because the jump in potential energy only affects the normal component of the velocity. Thus, the problem is 2D.
Namely you can write
$$\mathbf{v}_1 = v_{1,n} \hat{\mathbf{n}} +v_{t} \hat{\mathbf{t}} $$
$$\mathbf{v}_2 = v_{2,n} \hat{\mathbf{n}} +v_{t} \hat{\mathbf{t}} \ , $$
being $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ the normal direction and $\hat{\mathbf{t}}$ the tangential direction determined by the projection of the velocity
$$v_t \hat{\mathbf{t}} = \mathbf{v} - \hat{\mathbf{n}} \ \hat{\mathbf{n}} \cdot \mathbf{v}\ . $$
The jump in the potential affects only the normal component, since it is equivalent to the impulsive force
$$\mathbf{F} = - \nabla V = - \hat{\mathbf{n}} ( V_2 - V_1) \delta(z-z_{jump}) \ ,$$
with $z$ the coordinates in the normal direction. Integrating the second principle
$$m \dfrac{d}{dt}\mathbf{v} =\mathbf{F} = - \nabla V = - \hat{\mathbf{n}} ( V_2 - V_1) \delta(z-z_{jump}) $$
across the jump, reads
$$m (\mathbf{v}_2 - \mathbf{v}_1) = - \hat{\mathbf{n}} ( V_2 - V_1)$$

Thank you so much!
